# Android Fuel Library upload images 400 Error

Tags: android, web-services, multipart

I have this web service 
Url:   http://menatservice.menatbb.com/MenaServiceCommon.svc/TestUploadImage
Form Data:

`ListId : 10
ListType : 1
MenaImage:  >> put any image`

I tried

```
  val formData = listOf("ListId" to moduleId, "ListType" to moduleType,
                "MenaImage" to listOf{images[0].file.inputStream().readBytes()})
        this@UploadImageRequest.data1 = images[0].file.readBytes()
        return Constants.TestUploadImage.httpUpload(Method.POST, formData)
```

but I got 400 bad request error while in Postman it is working as the image below
what should I do to make it work by Fuel library?
[image]

Comment: have you tried sending your image inside Body[] part

Comment: @TejasPandya can you give me the code that implements it  by Fuel

Comment: i can't give you the code . but i can help you solve  your problem

Comment: @TejasPandya I need just the call, not a whole project, I tried .blobs - . dataparts . form-data in Fuel but nothing works for me